# Django: ModelForm on save returning object of Another Class

Tags: django, django-forms

ipdb debug:

```
ipdb> form_class
<class 'myproject.apps.usersites.forms.IndividualSiteHomeForm'>
ipdb> form = form_class(request.POST)
ipdb> form
<myproject.apps.usersites.forms.IndividualSiteHomeForm object at 0x021A81F0>
ipdb> var = form.save( commit= False)
ipdb> var
<IndividualProfile: user1>
ipdb> request.POST
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'208ff2a5a78bd5c2ba9452b365b59b6d'], u'ho
me_content': [u'Some contents']}>
```

I am saving a IndividualSiteHomeForm after binding it to POST data. 
Why is it returning a IndividualProfile Object?

For reference:
1> Model

```
class IndividualSite(SiteBase):
individual = models.ForeignKey(IndividualProfile, unique=True, verbose_name = _("Professional"))
logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="sites/logos/",verbose_name=_("logo"))    
home_content = models.TextField(_("Home contents"), null=True, blank=False,
                                help_text = "This text will appear on your web site home. Do not use HTML here.")    

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.individual.name
```

2> ModelForm

```
class IndividualSiteHomeForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = IndividualSite
    exclude = ('individual','user','logo')
```

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: To confirm var is indeed IndividualProfile:

```
ipdb> var
<IndividualProfile: user1>
ipdb> var.home_content
*** AttributeError: 'IndividualProfile' object has no attribute 'home_content'
ipdb> var.__class__
<class 'profiles.models.IndividualProfile'>
ipdb>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is returning an instance of `IndividualProfile`. I think it's returning an instance of `IndividualSite`, as you expect, but when you repr that from the shell, it uses the `__unicode__` method of IndividualSite - which returns the value of the ForeignKey, which is an IndividualProfile.

Comment: I am positive it is IndividualProfile object..please see the EDIT.